# Inserting multiple values from a function that returns a table - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How can I insert multiple rows from a function that returns a table ? Thanks for your help

I am trying this code but it is showing an error that it is ambiguous

Comment: Please, add `[a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts]` function definition or at least its return type along with your function definition and received error.

Comment: Edited to see [a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts]

Comment: it's strange function. I think You do not need join `[a01].[tbl_blockedAccounts]` because you don't use any fields from it. Can you tell what you mean writing this ( function )?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight -

```
INSERT INTO [a01].[tbl_notificationsInbox]
    (notificationID, notificationMessage, notificationDate, accountID, typeId)
SELECT NEWID(), @FrA+' has become friends with '+@FrB, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), accountID, 2
from  [a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts](@FriendA, @FriendB)
```

but it depends on `[a01].[udf_getAddedFriendContacts]` realization

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have any side-effects within a function. In your example `INSERT`ing into a persistent table and `NEWID`() are considered having side-effects (I understand the `INSERT`, but `NEWID`() looks like a normal function to me).

Error message is the following:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function.

Your function should look like the following:

```
alter function dbo.testGuidReturn
(
    @UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS @Ret TABLE
(
    notificationID          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    notificationMessage     NVARCHAR(100),
    notificationDate        DATETIME2,
    accountID               int,
    typeId                  INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Ret
    VALUES (@UID, 'Some message', GETDATE(), 10, 20)

    RETURN
END
GO

-- example call
SELECT * FROM dbo.testGuidReturn(NEWID())
```

Also, notice that `GETDATE` is accepted, although it is not deterministic.

**[EDIT]**

Due to clever trick indicated [here](http://create%20view%20vwGetNewId%20as%20select%20newid()%20as%20New_Id), function can be simplified: create a view to get the NEWID() and use it for your selection:

```
create view vwGetNewId as select newid() as New_Id
GO

alter function dbo.testGuidReturn()
RETURNS @Ret TABLE
(
    notificationID          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    notificationMessage     NVARCHAR(100),
    notificationDate        DATETIME2,
    accountID               int,
    typeId                  INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Ret
    SELECT New_Id, 'Some message', GETDATE(), 10, 20
    FROM vwGetNewId

    RETURN
END
GO
```